# Match all characters except the matching (multi word) pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I want to uppercase all the characters in a line except the matching pattern.

Pattern:

```
abc*
```

Input:

```
xyz a56abccc 789def
```

Result:

```
XYZ A56abccc 789DEF
```

Is it possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Why does result include an uppercase `A` when it it not supposed to be converted?

Comment: He means to only target the token at the end of the second word. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead based function:

```
var s = 'xyz a56abccc 789def';

var r = s.replace(/(?![abc])[a-z]/g, function($1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); });
//=> "XYZ a56abccc 789DEF"
```

`(?![abc])[a-z]` will match any lowercase letter except if it is one of them in the list i.e. `[abc]`

Comment: My regex was `(?![abc])[a-z]`. OP hasn't responded to the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of the above that passes the [test](https://regex101.com/r/qB5fK8/).

```
(?![abc]+\b)[a-z]
```

for

```
var s = 'xyz a56abccc 789def';

var r = s.replace(/(?![abc]+\b)[a-z]/g, function($1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); });
//=> "XYZ A56abccc 789DEF"
```